# Problem with aura and JS controller

Tags: apex, controller, picklist, aura, aura-iteration

I have a little problem. I have a simple program that gets a value from picklist , and using this value my program must show all values from the database

Thats my code

COMPONENT

```
<aura:attribute name="trueevents" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="picksel" type="String" />

<lightning:select aura:id="PicklistId" name="Sensors Pick List" label="Select a Sensor" required="true"
                  value="{!v.picksel}" onchange="{!c.getTrueEvents}">
    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.sensors}" var="item">  
            <option value="{!item.Name}" text="{!item.Name}" />  
        </aura:iteration>
        
</lightning:select>


<aura:iteration items="{!v.trueevents}" var="item">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td data-label="Events Data">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Sensor Name">
                            {!item.Sensor__r.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td data-label="Events Data">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Event_x">
                            {!item.x__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Events Data">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Event_y">
                            {!item.y__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Events Data">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Event_z">
                            {!item.z__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td data-label="Events Data">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Sensor Max Vectors Difference">
                            {!item.Sensor__r.Max_Vectors_Difference__c}</div>
                    </td>
                  
                </tr>            
                </aura:iteration>
```

CONTROLLER

```
getTrueEvents : function(component, event, helper) {
    var pickselected = component.find("PicklistId").get("v.value");
    console.log('pickselected--->>> ' + pickselected);
    var action = component.get("c.getTrueEvents");
    action.setParams({ searchName : pickselected});
    var self = this;                  
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        component.set('v.trueevents', actionResult.getReturnValue());
     });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

APEX CONTROLLER

```
@AuraEnabled
global static List<Sensor_Event__c> getTrueEvents(String searchName){

    List<Sensor_Event__c> events = new List<Sensor_Event__c>(
        [SELECT x__c, y__c, z__c, Sensor__r.Max_Vectors_Difference__c, Sensor__r.Name
         FROM Sensor_Event__c
         WHERE Sensor__r.name = :searchName] );
    return events;
}
```

Why have i gotten this mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot name your function in client side and apex class to be the same. "getTrueEvents"

Check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/275701/93221

Comment: Thank u! It helps!